# Android: ExpandableListActivity icons overlapping text

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to build a very simple ExpandableListActivity based on the API Demos [Sample Code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html):

[image: The default layout appears broken, as the expand/collapse icons overlap the list item text.]

Unfortunately, even though the demo just uses the default layout, the layout doesn't look right. It seems the text isn't indented enough, such that the expand/collapse icons overlap the list item text, as the screenshot demonstrates.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in the `getGenericTextView()` method of the sample code:

```
// Set the text starting position
textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
```

`setPadding(...)` sets the padding (intrinsic space) in pixels, meaning the result of this indenting approach will differ per device. You seem to be using an hdpi device with a relatively large horizontal screen resolution, resulting in visually too little space on the lefthand side of the TextView. For some more explanation on this issue, please read the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

That being said, you can easily overcome the problem by setting a *density independent pixel* (d(i)p) value, such that the visually indented space will be identical across different resolutions. You can use the [TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) utility class for this:

```
int dips = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 36, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Alternatively you could inflate a TextView from xml, on which you can set the density independent properties at design time, in stead of doing it on the fly at runtime.

Comment: but it doesn't address a layout that encompasses all screen sizes.  bandaid code.

Comment: @moonlightcheese: It's not meant as full solution, obviously. I'm sure you'll be able to figure some out using the pointers given.